# How to parse Soundcloud json response using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, soundcloud

Its only getting throught the track values. What I need is to get the username. Here is what Im usign, thanks

```
    {
        "items":[
        {
        "kind":"track",
        "id":33369455,
        "uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/33369455",
        "user":{
        "id":758840,
        "username":"JoeDreamer",
        "avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000006878204-maqsrd-large.jpg?923db0b"},
        "download_count":0,
        "comment_count":1
        },
        {
        "kind":"track",
        "id":33369455,
        "uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/33369455",
        "user":{
        "id":758840,
        "username":"JoeDreamer",
        "avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000006878204-maqsrd-large.jpg?923db0b"},
        "download_count":0,
        "comment_count":1
        }]
    }
```

```
    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://mydata.com/data.json"));
    foreach($user->items as $mydata)
    {
         echo $mydata->id . "\n";
         foreach($mydata->user as $value)
         {
              echo $value->username . "\n";
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://mydata.com/data.json"));
foreach($user->items as $mydata)
{
     echo $mydata->id . "\n";
     echo $mydata->user->username;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding an additional flag to the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function, we can tell the function to return an associative array instead of objects.

> json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false ])

If you elect to use `json_decode` like this, your tasks becomes quite a lot simpler. You can access the username as if you were accessing a multidimensional array.

```
$user = json_decode($str,true);  // notice the "true" argument here
foreach($user['items'] as $mydata)
{
    echo $mydata['id'] . "," . $mydata['user']['username'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might have missed is that `$myData-user` is an object within itself. PHP's [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function works recursively passing over every element of the JSON string you use.

```
{
  "kind":"track",
  ...
  "user":{
    "id":758840,
    "username":"JoeDreamer",
    ...
  }
}
```

You'll have to access the username as a property of it's parent element. By adding the additional `key` variable to the inner `foreach` loop, we can inspect the key name and only select the `username` property.

```
...
foreach($mydata->user as $key=>$value){
  if ($key == 'username'){
    echo $value . "\n";
  }
}
```

The additional loop however, is redundant. Unless you have some certain specific need to loop over every one of the properties, you could simply access the username directly like this -

```
$mydata->user->username
```